# KaiOS infinite scrolling

Tags: kaios

I have a little issue with scrolling in KaiOS. I would like to have the first element selected when the user goes down on the last element.
So, I used `document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();` to get the first element into the view. Works fine in the WebIDE, but not on the real phone.

I also tried `scrollElement.scrollBy({ top: -(document.documentElement.scrollHeight), left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });`.
When I try it in the console it works fine, but when executes in the app, it doesn't. Maybe it has something to do with the .focus on the element, I have no idea. Is there a good example for this kind of scrolling? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `false` as a parameter to the `scrollIntoView()` API:

```js
document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView(false)
```

**Alternatively**

There might be an issue with the calculated screen height on the phone. This can possibly lead to this anomaly. Keep a check on the screen height on the phone and the overflow behaviour of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the first element focusable(tabindex) and then `.focus()` the element, the `.focus()` function scrolls the element into view.